# Error was not declared in this scope

Tags: c, scope, this

I'm making this simple code where if I put two numbers and it shows the solution. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter two numbers:")
    ;scanf("&d &d", a, b)
    ;printf("=======================\n"); /*  */
    /*  */
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d.\n\n", 3, 4, 3 + 4)
    /*  */
    ;printf("The difference of %d and %d is %d. \n\n", 3, 4, 3-4)
    /*  */
    ;printf("The product of %d and %d is %d. \n\n", 3, 4, 3*4)
    /* sum of squares would be a*a + b*b */
    ;printf("The sum of the squares of %d and %d is %d. \n\n", 3, 4, 3*3 + 4*4)
    ;printf("**end**"); /* :-) */ 
    ;return (0);
}
```

and I keep getting an error that says:

```
[Error] 'a' was not declared in this scope 
and
[Error] 'b' was not declared in this scope
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: you need to declare them, as it says. like "int a, b;"

Comment: Interesting style :_( .

Comment: You need to declare the variables a and b, before you try to store anything in them.

Comment: @this more like "wtf is this" style.

Comment: i have no idea but this is the description of my assignment:                              The following program is supposed to take two integers and output their sum, difference, product, and the sum of their squares.  Complete the program so that it runs correctly.  (Do not print any blank lines following the last output line.)

Comment: also im a newbie here so it would do me a great favor if you could explain it further or maybe answer it for me :))))

Comment: there are 3 answers to this minute. Pick one that you find most helpful or if there are things unclear, ask further questions

Comment: ok i did what you told me to do but the "Enter two numbers" is missing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the declaration if the two variables is missing.
Declare them first, in your case int would be best, so:

```
int a, b;
```

then you also need to pass pointers to the scanf() function, so it can write the values in the variables, like so:

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

it's also good practice to check if the values have been read at all or not. scanf() returns the number of values it successfully parsed from the input, so in your case it should return 2 if successful, test for that.

Also it's not a bad idea to initialize your variables as well, so maybe do it like that instead:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
```

also you don't seem to be using the variables in the rest of your program, you might want to do something about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables before you try to store anything in them.

```
int  a,b;
```

That line needs to be the first line in your main function.

EDIT: Make SURE your code looks like this?

```
int main()
{
    int  a,b;
    printf("Enter two numbers:")
    ;scanf("&d &d", a, b)
    ;printf("=======================\n"); /*  */
    /*  */
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d.\n\n", 3, 4, 3 + 4)
    /*  */
    ;printf("The difference of %d and %d is %d. \n\n", 3, 4, 3-4)
    /*  */
    ;printf("The product of %d and %d is %d. \n\n", 3, 4, 3*4)
    /* sum of squares would be a*a + b*b */
    ;printf("The sum of the squares of %d and %d is %d. \n\n", 3, 4, 3*3 + 4*4)
    ;printf("**end**"); /* :-) */ 
    ;return (0);
}
```

Comment: where exactly do i put that???                                                                        p.s im a newbie

Comment: @Naxs before you use the variables. So essentially in your case before you call scanf(). Sometimes it's a good idea to declare all variables at the start of the function, makes it a bit clearer what is used in the function.

Comment: ok so i did what you told me but the "Enter two numbers" is missing from my output

Comment: Check my edit. Be certain your code looks like what I posted. There is no reason that the "Enter two numbers" would disappear. Don't worry about being a newbie!

Comment: thanks man i just entered college and im on my 4th week of information technology so im pretty much on the learning stage.. anyways tnx for the answers!!!!!!! :)))

Comment: No problem. Also, please, please put your semicolons on the same line as the statement. instead of the next line. They are called delimiters. They denote when the statement is over, not when another one begins. Obviously it is not causing any compilation errors, but people will probably look at your code with distaste if you write it like that.

Answer (score 0):

1.It's compulsory to declare variable before using.
You are using a and b in below line. but you haven't declared it before. So it will give you error surely.

```
scanf("&d &d", a, b);
```

2.It's also compulsory to use '&' with a and b while getting value from user. It won't give you error but can give you incorrect results that you don't want.

```
scanf("&d &d", &a, &b);
```

3.Indentation is also not good. You need to use ';' at the end of statement  instead of before stating next statement or any other coding line. It won't give you error but it easy to  understand code and easily readability.

```
printf("Enter two numbers:")
;scanf("&d &d", a, b)
```

Comment: it's kinda redundant what the parameters are if your format string does not contain any format specifiers (e.g. `%d`)